SSRS on a Secondary Replica
We have an availability group database with 4 servers which includes a asynchronous replica that is used for reporting. Sometimes due to large query sets the secondary replica stops synchronization and we have to resume synchronization manually.
We also want to install SSRS on the secondary replica that we use for reporting.
Here are my below questions

Is it worth the performance hit to install SSRS on secondary replica as we don't have Enterprise license to install SSRS on a separate host.

Can we separate the secondary report server and synchronize data through SSIS hence there will be 3 node availability group database servers and one separate report server which synchronizes through SSIS or some other form .


Overall is it advisable to RUN SSRS on the secondary replica. Thanks for the input

To be clear, you want to install the SSRS report engine on that server and also host the databases of that SSRS instance on it?

So you have a secondary replica that is not entirely healthy, and you're asking if you should install a web application on that server as well?
No. The answer is no.  If everything was running great, and you had lots of unused memory and CPU on the secondary, and you're willing to run both SSRS and your primary DB on the server during failovers, then perhaps.
